# How many temperature sensors does a Chevrolet Aveo 2005 have?

Tags: chevrolet, temperature, aveo

I want to know if the Chevrolet Aveo 2005 (4dr Sdn) has only one temperature sensor or has two.

I now that it has the [ECT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001W0FSMM) sensor that triggers the cooling fan among other things, but recently someone told me that the temperature showed in the board comes from another sensor.

I don't know if this is true and i was not able to find the other sensor.

Comment: I'm only able to find the one coolant sensor as well. Some older cars had it this way, but pretty sure since around the turn of the century, cars pretty much only needed one sensor (this probably depends on the car, though) since the dash is run by the computer. Everything feeds into the computer and the computer controls the dash.

Comment: Yes, I've been searching and found that two sensors were normally used in older cars, but didn't found anything specific about the aveo 2005, and well I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: There's only a single sensor on that MY.

Comment: Keep in mind that some sensors (such as the one in VW Passats from that era) have two separate sensors in one physical housing. Each sensor must have a separate electrical feed, although multiple sensors may share a ground connection.